# Yes or No in Bash

Tags: bash

I am a new user of BASH script, however this is not my 1st time programming. I am just wondering, how do I forward the parameter of Yes/No question in my program? After the user inputs yes in the console, the program would start from the beginning. How do I do that?

Comment: Forward to what? If you just want to store the input in a variable use `read`: `read -p 'continue the program: [y/n] ' answer`. The user input will be stored in `answer`

Comment: I'd recommend reading over [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid downvotes.

Comment: You do it like in virtually any other programming language: You wrapp the whole code into an endless loop, and bash offers the command `break` to break  out from the loop, and `continue` to just go on with the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Read input, check your condition, and exit on fail, is a common pattern.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Continue? (yes/no): " continue && [[ $continue == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1
echo "Do stuff if they answer yes"
```